Number palindrome function doesn't return largest palindrome
I'm trying to make a function that finds the largest palindrome made of 3-digit factors. When I run the code, it finds a palindrome, but it's not the largest. Don't criticize my code, especially the goto, as I'm pretty new to C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPalindrome(int number) {
    int palindrome = 1;
    char *str = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(str, "%d", number);
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((str[i] == str[len - (i+1)]) && palindrome) continue;
        else palindrome = 0;
    }
    free(str);
    return palindrome;
}

int main(void) {
    char* omg = "\xF0\x9F\x98\xB2";
    int factorI = 0;
    int factorJ = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
            if (isPalindrome(i * j)) {
                factorI = i;
                factorJ = j;
                goto end_loop;
            }
        }
    }
    end_loop: printf("Done! Found palindrome. (%s%s%s)\n", omg, omg, omg);
    printf("i: %d\nj: %d\n", factorI, factorJ);
    printf("PALINDROME: %d", factorI * factorJ);
    printf("\n\nHello World\n");
    return 0;
}

When I run the code, I get this:
Done! Found palindrome. ()
i: 995
j: 583
PALINDROME: 580085

Hello World

But that doesn't seem to be the biggest palindrome, because when I enter it into Project Euler, it marks the solution as incorrect. Can anyone help debug my code and see where I messed up? I looked over it like three times and I found nothing. PLEASE don't tell me the correct factors/palindrome, just help me with my code.

Have you thoroughly tested isPalindrome to ensure it works? Note that to check for a string being a palindrome, you only have to loop halfway through.

Well, I don't see any code comparing palindromes that saves the max? Other notes, "%d" in sprintf() can have 12 characters requiring a storage of at least 13 bytes to store as a string. Simply use char str[32] and avoid malloc() it's not needed (rule: never skimp on buffer size...). Also if you do use mailloc() it's char *str = malloc (nbytes); You don't need sizeof(char) that's 1. and see Do I cast the result of malloc? And... your use of goto is perfectly fine -- it's the only single command way to break nested loops in C :)

Look at your main nested loop.  As soon as it finds the very first palindrome, it immediately jumps to end_loop and prints it.  It's not finding the largest palindrome.  It's finding the first one it encounters.

You may think looping backwards ensures that you find the largest number. It doesn't. Consider the simple case of looping both i and j down from 3 to 1. Your loop goes like 9,6,3,6,4,2,3,2,1. If both 3 and 4 are valid, you'll find 3, instead of 4.

Also, you don't need to loop i < len, just i < len/2 since you are comparing a byte from each end and working toward the middle. Another way is to just set i = 0 and j = len - 1 and then loop while (i < j) { /* do stuff */; i++, j--; }.

"Don't criticize my code [..] as I'm pretty new to C" – this is quite a strange sentiment, as you're new don't you want to learn to become better?

Does Project Euler specify emojis as part of the answer?

@GuyIncognito -- I think the sentiment there is they would like help, but would rather not be insulted. Which ideally is how every question should be handled. Agree with n.m., unless you must have the emoji's, they are not really needed and are not portable across terminals anyway. Most will just see square boxes.

@Chris well I'm not asking about my palindrome function. It's PERFECT. Sorry about the wording, I made it last night at 10pm.

@David I like sizeof(char) for eye candy, because it shows that I'm not just typing random numbers. So when I do sizeof(int), it always returns 4, but you know how much bytes your int will take.

@OnyxWingman across platforms, sizeof(int) will not always return 4.

@TomKarzes I'm not sure where I got that wrong, but now that I look at it... no palindrome with three digit factors could possibly use a factor larger than 995, but what if we used a palindrome smaller than 995 with one bigger than 583 that would yield a larger palindrome? If I were to loop through I and J fully, that would loop 800,000 times, and that's sure to make my program be running forever, and I don't want to wait an hour for my code to go through I and J fully. Is there a way I could do this faster?

@Chris but sizeof(char) always returns four?

sizeof(char) always returns 1.

@WeijunZhou ah, I think I get it now! Thanks!

@n.m.couldbeanAI Really, I'm just writing in code to get an answer. Project Euler accepts a number, but I don't want to cheat and ask AI... I want to do it how they would do it back in the day, with C.

The point being made is that int isn't required to be 4-bytes by the C-standard, it can be 2, etc.. There are some unicorn implementations, ancient hardware, etc. that do not use 4-bytes for int. In the current world, ike a unicorn, I haven't seen one, but there are those that swear they exist. In the past, they were quite frequent. Many 8-bit and 16-bit processors came before the 32 and 64-bit world.

Computers can perform several billion operations per second. Looping 800k times is not going to be a problem by itself.

Your algorithm is faulty. For each number from 999 to 100 it then loops from 999 to 100 and checks for the first palindromic number. But this is not the largest such number.
That is 906609 and is formed by 913 and 993. Your algorithm never reaches this combination because it found a combo of 995 and a much smaller number first.
You can use your loops, but you need to continue looping and compare to a maximum. We'll start by setting this to 0.
int main(void) {
    int factorI = 0;
    int factorJ = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
            int ij = i * j;
            if (isPalindrome(ij) && ij > max) {
                factorI = i;
                factorJ = j;
                max = ij;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Done! Found palindrome.\n");
    printf("i: %d\nj: %d\n", factorI, factorJ);
    printf("PALINDROME: %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}

We can optimize a bit by not checking duplicates. If we've checked 999, 995, there's no reason to check 995, 999.
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j >= 100; j--) {
            int ij = i * j;
            if (isPalindrome(ij) && ij > max) {
                factorI = i;
                factorJ = j;
                max = ij;
            }
        }
    }

Optimizing further
We can realize that if we find a matching three digit j for a given value of i, if we try a smaller value of i, we're not going to get a bigger product with a smaller value of j. So we need to dynamically set the lower bound for j.
int main(void) {
    int factorI = 0;
    int factorJ = 0;
    int max = 0;

    int min_j = 100;

    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j >= min_j; j--) {
            int ij = i * j;
            if (isPalindrome(ij) && ij > max) {
                factorI = i;
                factorJ = j;
                max = ij;
                min_j = j;
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Done! Found palindrome.\n");
    printf("i: %d\nj: %d\n", factorI, factorJ);
    printf("PALINDROME: %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}

For three digit numbers this means that for i = 999, 998, 997, 996 we'll have to test all the way down to 100. But, on i = 995 we'll find a match at j = 583. We'll note that this is the largest palidrome found so far with factors 995 and 583 and break the inner loop. Now for i = 994, 993 we're only looping j down to 583 rather than needlessly to 100. For i = 993 we find a match at 913. This means that for the remaining loops we iterate j from:
992 -> 913
991 -> 913
990 -> 913
989 -> 913
988 -> 913
...
914 -> 913
913 -> 913
912 -> 913

Oh, look at that, all of the remaining iterations of i do nothing.
The isPalindrome function
This works with your existing isPalindrome, but that can be greatly improved by removing the dynamic memory allocation, only looping halfway over the string, and cleaning up the control flow in your loop.
int isPalindrome(int number) {
    char str[32];
    sprintf(str, "%d", number);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[len - (i+1)]) 
            return 0; 
    }
    
    return 1;
}


:(. I left a message in bold at the end of my question, you probably didn't see it. Anyways, nice answer! EDIT: I guess it helps to explain your code, nevermind.

Oh, no! I don't have a reason to use goto anymore!

Also, this answer is what I was avoiding in the first place. I don't want to loop through all the 800K possible factors. Is there any possible way to avoid that, for compile time purposes? Let's just say... my computer is a bit slower.

You might flip this on its head. Start from 999*999 which is 998001 and count down to find palindromic numbers, then determine if they are the product of two three digit factors. The question you need to answer then, is doing that 91392 times less expensive that the approach shown here?

I guess not. It seemed to run fine on my computer.
